# PYFHEL - Concatenating two encrypted strings and then decoding them

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm trying out the [PYFHEL (PYthon For Homomorphic Encryption Libraries)](https://github.com/ibarrond/Pyfhel) library, and was wondering if it was possible to concatenate two strings while encrypted and then decrypt the result.

This probably better explains what I want to do:

```
string1 = "hi "
string2 = "there"

*encrypt both strings separately*

encrypted_string1 + encrypted_string2 = result

*decrypt result*

decrypted_result = "hi there"
```

So in short, I have two strings - `"hi"` and `"there"`. Upon encrypting both these strings separately, I would like to be able to concatenate both of them, to form a result that, when decoded, reads `"hi there"`.

I understand that PYFHEL doesn't allow you to directly encrypt a string, it has to be an `int` in order to be encrypted/decrypted, so am I able to do anything in order to convert both these strings into integers, encrypt them, then "add" them together so that when decrypted and turned back into a string, it reads "hey there"?

What I'm asking may be impossible, I don't know. I'm new to all this and am just very bored on the school holidays. I hope someone understands what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You cannot go from `"hi"` and `"there"` to `"hi there"`, only to `"hithere"` I suppose. Please always be precise. The trick is to find the mathematical operations that describe string concatenation. Hint: to shift data to the left you can perform $i \cdot N^x$ where $i$ is the index of a character the alphabet, $N$ is the alphabet size (e.g. 256 for a byte) and $x$ is the number of positions you want it to shift.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Oh yeah, I understand why it''d be "hithere" instead. Thanks! Thanks for that hint too, that really helps!